# I want to keep .0 when use ngx-mask in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-mask

when I use `ngx-mask` in angular, it automatically deletes .0 when server response 1.0, `ex: 1.0 => 1`
So I want to prevent this.

`1.0 keep 1.0 not 1` when use `ngx-mask`

Comment: Can you show us code?

Comment: <input
[(ngModel)]="numberDecimal"
decimalMarker="."
thousandSeparator=""
mask="separator.4" separatorLimit="99999"
>

Comment: This is my code in .html file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are consistent with decimal points then you can consider using **number pipe**. Good luck!

```
{{ tr | number : '1.2-2'}}
```

Here is the example if you are using [(ngModel)].
[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-example-srhzgq?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I use ngModel, so pipe is not work in this case

Comment: In that case, you can have [ngModel] and (ngModelChange). [(ngModel)] is just the syntactic sugar over them.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-example-srhzgq?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Replace (ngModelChange) with (change). So that code looks clean.